# UIImageView's image not getting changed on postnotification in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, nsnotificationcenter

In my app I have a UIImageView and at runtime once I download the image I am changing the image through postnotification but the image was not getting changed and I checked all my connections in nib and everywhere and it looks fine for me but still the image was not getting displayed can anyone help me in this regard. And my uiimageview was inside a scrollview and the scrollview was inside my main view

the following method was called on postnotification

```
- (void) refreshimages:(NSNotification *)notofication {
    if ([[notofication name] isEqualToString:@"DownloadImgBinary"]) {
        [activityview stopAnimating];
        [activityview removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];
        [self.scrollView bringSubviewToFront:imgCamera];
        self.imgCamera.image = td.imgPhoto;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check *two things*.

**First,** make sure that you are actually receiving the notification.

Put a breakpoint in the observer's target method, or stick an NSLog in there. If, when you do this, you see neither of them, then your notification isn't getting received.

**Second,** make sure that the image is actually getting downloaded.

Either use a web debugging proxy (I use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) but it costs a bit, there are alternatives), or again, breakpoint somewhere. Or stick in a manual button somewhere that on-press tries to set the UIImageView's image, run the app, and press the button after you're sure the image downloaded.

**Finally,** to make sure something fishy isn't going on, stick two images in your project, give the imageView a default image (something glaringly obvious like checkerboard pattern), and then in the notification (assuming it is firing), set it to something else that is also glaringly obvious. Then test. This way you know that the bring-subview-to-front is working, and that your IB links are working.